# ORDER BY two conditions

Tags: mysql, sql

I try to achieve the following: I have messages with different colors (`red`, `orange`, `green`). Now I like to sort my resultset from the messages posted in the last three ours by the following condition:

- If the newest message is green that should be on top
- Any other messages should be sorted by the following order: 1. `red`, 2. `orange`, 3. `green`

So here's the SQL I've so far. But this does not handle the case when a green message has been posted most recent:

```
SELECT ID, color
FROM mod_cc_stream_entry
WHERE DATE_ADD(status_date, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) >= NOW()
ORDER BY FIELD(COALESCE(color, 'green'), 'red', 'orange', 'green')
```

I could run two statements. First to check if the newest message is `green` and if not run a second statement to get the order I like (statement above).

But I like to know if there is a possbility to do that in one statement.

**UPDATE** [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/14115a)

Comment: can you please provide some data?

Comment: also an example of how the output should look would be helpful too

Comment: Not that immediately springs to mind. As the newest green message will be max 1 row it will probably have little impact on performance so you could try just linking the queries up using UNION.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

at a first guess you could try something like a conditional order by

### QUERY:

```
SELECT ID, color
FROM mod_metanet_cc_stream_entry
JOIN (
    SELECT MAX(status_date) as new_status 
    FROM mod_metanet_cc_stream_entry
) temp
WHERE DATE_ADD(status_date, INTERVAL 3 HOUR) >= NOW()
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN status_date = new_status AND color = 'green' THEN 1
        WHEN color = 'red' THEN 2
        WHEN color = 'orange' THEN 3
        WHEN color is null THEN 8
        ELSE 4
    END
```

I would need some data to test it though

### OUTPUT:

```
+----+--------+
| ID | COLOR  |
+----+--------+
| 20 | red    |
| 26 | red    |
| 17 | red    |
| 23 | red    |
| 16 | orange |
| 24 | orange |
| 21 | orange |
| 27 | orange |
| 18 | green  |
| 19 | green  |
| 22 | NULL   |
| 25 | NULL   |
+----+--------+
```

Comment: Thx you got what I mean :-). But it does not work correct :-(. See my updated question with the SQLFiddle at the end. So with this data you should get a `red` record first. DATETIMES are `UTC`.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER i figured it out... it was a comparrison on each date to itself... you just need to join the min date separately and it works fine

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER did you try my most recent update?? it works both ways

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER sqlfiddle isn't working for me so i translated over to my local... if you notice here I added another row with id 28 that is green and has the most recent date http://cl.ly/image/3v0M0w1a0t3T

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER and then again here without the green column being the most recent... http://cl.ly/image/3V272A323I0B

Comment: I checked by running the query given in this answer on my local setup. It looks like working as expected, unless OP's expectation is something else.

Comment: Perfect. Thanky you very much. I suggested an edit so you can simplify it a bit. Basically there's no `DATE_ADD()` needed for getting the entry with the most recent date and thus it's not necessary to use it on the comparision in the first `WHEN` argument.

Comment: @TiMESPLiNTER yup youre right... before i had it when it was min() date... but it needed to be max date so the where is obsolete :)

Answer (score 0):

Using inputs from John Ruddell's answer, I am getting the last time first using a query and then using it in the order by clause.

```
SET @const = 3;
SET @last_time = (SELECT status_date FROM mod_metanet_cc_stream_entry WHERE DATE_ADD(status_date, INTERVAL @const HOUR) >= NOW() ORDER BY status_date DESC LIMIT 1);

SELECT ID, color, status_date
FROM mod_metanet_cc_stream_entry
WHERE DATE_ADD(status_date, INTERVAL @const HOUR) >= NOW()
ORDER BY
    CASE 
        WHEN (status_date = @last_time AND color = 'green') THEN 1
        WHEN color = 'red' THEN 2
        WHEN color = 'orange' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END;
```

Comment: only because you gave credit to where credit is due i'm giving a +1 :) I hate it when people basically copy my answer and dont give credit :D thanks

Comment: Oh thanks a lot @John Ruddell. You made my day! :) Feeling great answering after a long long time.